# Optimize EF Core query with Include()

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, optimization, entity-framework-core

I have following query within my project and it is consuming lot of time to execute. I am trying to optimize it, but not able to successfully do it. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

```
_context.MainTable
.Include(mt => mt.ChildTable1)
.Include(mt => mt.ChildTable1.ChildTable2)
.Include(mt => mt.ChildTable3)
.Include(mt => mt.ChildTable3.ChildTable4)
.SingleOrDefault(
        mt =>
        mt.ChildTable3.ChildTable4.Id == id 
        &&
        mt.ChildTable1.Operation == operation
        && 
        mt.ChildTable1.Method = method
        && 
        mt.StatusId == statusId);
```

Comment: Do you need every column from MainTable, ChildTable1, ChildTable2, ChildTable3 and ChildTable4 OR can you narrow down the data columns you need in the result set?

Comment: See the section on Explicit Loading here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data  Too many Includes can create poor queries.  Either of the two techniques for Explicit Loading can be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

`Include()` gets translates to join and you are using too many joins in the code. You can optimize indexes with the help of DB engine execution plan.

I suggest you not to use all `Include` in one go. instead, you break the query and apply `Include` one by one. I meant you apply `Include, get the result and then apply the`Include`again and so..By having more than two`Include` affect the performance.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that the Include() was the culprit. I removed all the Include() from the query and used traditional Join(). I got significant improvement in performance. The original query with multiple Include() used to take 1-1.5 minutes to execute. After we modified it with Join(), it is now executing in 2-3 seconds. It seems though Include statement generates Joins in background, the way it generates the join logic is complicated and causes performance issues. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't see any performance issues with you query.

Since you have a singleOrDefault I would look at uptimizing the database call. If you have analytics tools available then in SQL Server Management Studio then you choose tools > Sql Server Profiler. Get query into SQL Server Management Studio, mark the query and choose "Analyse Query in Database Engine Tuning advisor"