# EF Core 3, optimize lots of Include/ThenInclude

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a query like this

```
return await _ctx.Activities
            .Include(a => a.Attributes)
            .Include(a => a.Roles)
            .Include(a => a.Bookmarks)
            .Include(a => a.VideoMetas)
                .ThenInclude(vm => vm.Instances)
            .Include(a => a.ImageMetas)
                .ThenInclude(im => im.Instances)
            .Include(a => a.Procedure)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.Attributes)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);
```

Which turns out to be very slow. In `EF 6` you can do `.Include(v => v.VideoMetas.Select(vm => vm.Instances)` which is a bit faster (I guess, haven't looked at SQL Profiler and actual query tbh). How can I optimize that? I can also use `EF Plus` where it has `.IncludeOptimized()` but there is no version for `.ThenInclude()`. I heard I can use `.Select` instead of `.Include()` but really not sure how I can handle that in this query.

Comment: Maybe helpful comments an answer [quention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52222999/10470443)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to split it into multiple queries, to speed up the performance.
You can use explicit loading for this.
It's not the prettiest solution, but it works. Hopefully an easier solution will come in EF 5.

I'm guessing a bit on which fields are collections and which are "normal" entries, but something like this:

```cs
var activity = await _ctx.Activities.FindAsync(Id);

await context.Entry(activity)
    .Collection(a => a.Attributes)
    .LoadAsync();

await context.Entry(activity)
    .Collection(a => a.Roles)
    .LoadAsync();

await context.Entry(activity)
    .Collection(a => a.Bookmarks)
    .LoadAsync();

await context.Entry(activity)
    .Collection(a => a.VideoMetas)
    .Query()
    .Include(vm => vm.Instances)
    .LoadAsync();
 
await context.Entry(activity)
    .Collection(a => a.ImageMetas)
    .Query()
    .Include(im => im.Instances)
    .LoadAsync();

await context.Entry(activity)
    .Reference(a => a.Procedure)
    .Query()
    .Include(p => p.Attributes)
    .LoadAsync();

return activity;
```

**Update : As of EF Core 5 Microsoft have added `.AsSplitQuery()` which allows doing this much less verbose with eager loading!**

Comment: how to use this if you want to load all activates

Answer (score 2):

You can not. This is dimensional expansion SQL fights with. Ef 2.2 had what coudl be seen as an attempt to start with this, but they did not get it working and removed it.

Your best chance is to load in multiple (possibly parallel) queries and then stitch the results together in memory. For EF there are libraries to do that - not sure they exist for EfCore. They run the queries as multiple queries.

Comment: Adding to Tom's answer. This is a result of non well thought breaking change in EF Core 3.0 without providing a good way to get the multi query option back. There are several related issues in their GitHub issue tracker, here [Significant Query Slowdown When Using Multiple Joins Due To Changes In 3.0 #18022](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18022) you can find the discussion as well as the ridiculous (especially for no tracking queries) "solution" provided by one of the EF Core team members.

Comment: But you COULD jsut use Entity Frameworo Plus (google, open source). which does add a LOT of functionality back ;) Including IncludeOptimized which does - yes, exactly this. This is the funny thing. Some competent developers do what EfCore developers can not get working and a LOT more.

Comment: Exactly! Just I rather call it SAD fact :( But that seems to be the direction in all newer MSFT stack.

Comment: Yes, but `EF Core Plus` doesn't have an option for `.ThenInclude()`

Answer (score 0):

This query is bound to run slow as when parsing this to SQL will create very complex queries with all columns selected from all tables. Best thing for optimizing performance when working with these queries is to break into multiple queries and using select to select only those columns that are required.